# Not a Question: Popularizing Skeptics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I had the good fortune to attend TAM2012 this year.  A noted skeptic by the name of Tim Farley (who runs http://whatstheharm.net as well as a few other skeptical web resources) gave a talk.  The JREF has put the talk up on YouTube:  ["You are the Future of Skepticism on the Internet" - Tim Farley - TAM 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaB8rZ-AoOg&feature=youtu.be)

He also has a [Skeptics.SE account](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/284/tim-farley)!

At 25:51 into this talk, you all may recognize a website he shows on his powerpoint.

Just wanted to pass this along.  :)

Comment: Closed as “not a real question”. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph That made me chortle!  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a pretty cool avatar for an icon there.  :)  Stands out quite nicely.  I was wondering if SE has tried to collaborate more with the JREF as well as with Tim directly?  I think that would be a good opportunity for you all.  At least get that Web of Trust thing Tim mentioned in the video as something that will increase the likelyhood of people coming to the website as a source of reliable answers to things out there.